# Calendar parameter not showing in asp report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created an asp webpage that calls an ssrs report using reportviewer (v11).
The calendar parameter works fine when viewing from the ssrs report server but when viewed from the asp page, the calendar drowdown is not showing, any ideas why?

This only happens when I view the asp page from chrome. it works fine in IE. Is there any fixes for this?

Comment: I think this is a known issue. Chrome really does have problems rendering SSRS. Possibly Microsoft wanting you to continue using  IE.

Comment: This might help https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-report-fix/fjbdfjiheheafbioiejbdpalmojkeobk

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still looking for solutions.

Comment: Anyone who finds this old question and is still having issues: See the answer on a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75165023/187526