# Why doesn't the calendar controls show in the MvcReportViewer control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MvcReportViewer, downloaded from NuGet in Visual Studio 2022, MVC project.
The problem is that the calendar control does not show in the report that is rendered for date parameters; it only shows text boxes for dates. This happens in both Edge and Chrome. Is there a way for the calendar controls to show for date parameters?

My razor code:

```
@model OIG.WebUI.ViewModels.ReportViewModel
@using DataModel;
@using MvcReportViewer

@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Test Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml";
 }

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      &nbsp;
   </div>


<div class="col-sm-8">
    @Html.MvcReportViewer(
          "/Reports/SampleReport",null,null,null,
            new Dictionary<string, object> { { "name_id", @Model.User.name_id.ToString() 
 }, 
{ "BEGDATE", DateTime.Now }, 
{ "ENDDATE", null } },null,

            new { Height = 900, Width = 900, style = "border: none" },

       System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post

            )

</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just spent way too long tracking this down in our MVC application.  Here's what I found:

**The short answer is: Make sure you are using at least version 11.0.3452.0 of  Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL**

**For us, that involved adding the NuGet package: Microsoft.ReportViewer.2012.Runtime version 11.0.3452**

The problem turns out to be that in older packages (we had a hard coded reference to version 11.0.2802.16 of that DLL) it used a naive approach to checking for the Safari browser.

The CalendarDropDownInputControl is the class used for the popup calendar controls on Date fields in the parameters.  To check to see if the browser supports the calendar popup, it uses the following method:

```
// Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.CalendarDropDownInputControl 

public static bool IsSupported(IBrowserDetection browserDetection)
{
    if (!browserDetection.IsSafari)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar is GregorianCalendar;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this method returns false, the control is not rendered.

That method eventually calls IsSafari() which is implemented as follows in version 11.0.2802.16:

```
// Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.BrowserDetectionUtility
private static string SafariUserAgent => "SAFARI";
public static bool IsSafari(HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request == null || request.UserAgent == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return request.UserAgent.IndexOf(SafariUserAgent, 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

The Chrome User Agent string (as of this writing) is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Since the Chrome User Agent contains the string "Safari", it is detected as a Safari browser and the calendar controls do not render.

You can verify that this user agent is causing the issue, by changing the User Agent string in Chrome to anything that does not have Safari in it (like the Firefox one)

As of DLL version 11.0.3452.0, the browser detection code was changed to:

```
// Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.BrowserDetectionUtility
private static string ChromeUserAgent => "CHROME";
private static string SafariUserAgent => "SAFARI";

public static bool IsSafari(string userAgent)
{
    if (userAgent == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (userAgent.IndexOf(ChromeUserAgent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return userAgent.IndexOf(SafariUserAgent, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

This updated code checks for the string "CHROME" before checking for the string "SAFARI", causing the calendar popups to work with Chrome browsers.

I believe that it would also work to ensure the current runtime is installed on the web server:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747
But this is untested by me.

When in doubt, use a reflection tool (I used ILSpy) to check the DLL yourself for the implementation.